# Bash if condition to check if a ubuntu package has a newer version?

Tags: linux, bash, apt

I need a bash line to check if a ubuntu package needs an upgrade or not.

For example, I want to check if the package 'firefox' needs an upgrade using dpkg or apt-get commands.

Hypthetical Example:

```
# Hypothetical example pseudo-code
if [[ $(firefox_needs_upgrade) ]]; then echo "Firefox needs upgrading";fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bash function:

```
apt_needs_upgrade() {

    NEEDS_UPGRADE=$(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep "^$1$" | wc -l)

    if [ "$NEEDS_UPGRADE" == 1 ]; then
        return 0; # 0 means true in bash!!!
    else
        return 1; # false
    fi;
}
```

## Use it:

```
if apt_needs_upgrade "firefox"; then
    echo "Needs upgrading"
else
    echo "No need to upgrade"
fi;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
PACKAGE="firefox"
TMP_FILE="/tmp/upgrade_list"

apt-get -yqq update
apt-get -sqq upgrade | grep Inst > ${TMP_FILE}
grep -qi ${PACKAGE} ${TMP_FILE}

if [ $? == 0 ]
then
   echo "${PACKAGE} needs to be upgraded"
fi
```

Comment: Tried it and its not working. apt-get -sqq upgrade ... >${TMP_FILE}" is writing nothing to the file?

Comment: The script is working fine in my ubuntu box, do you have an error message ? How did you run the script ?

Answer (score 2):

Following command would help you  :-
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
or
cat /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available

For more details you can check the link below :-

https://askubuntu.com/questions/49958/how-to-find-the-number-of-packages-needing-update-from-the-command-line

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: I'm interested in a specific package and a bash if condition to handle it.

Comment: Based on the links you provided, I wrote a bash function to do the check correctly. Thanks, this is the second most useful answer, mine will be the first : )

Answer (score 0):

Ok edited my answer with a tested code. It's maybe a more pretty way to do it :

```
#retrieving info about the package
dpkg -l $1 >/dev/null

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then

 echo "$1 not installed or issue retrieving informations"
 exit

else

 #We check if pkg is upgradable
 UPGRADABLE=$(apt-get -s upgrade -u | egrep -c "^Conf $1 |^Inst $1 ")

 if [ $UPGRADABLE -gt 0 ]
 then
  echo "$1 need an upgrade"
 else
  echo "$1 up to date"
 fi

fi
```

usage :

```
# /tmp/check.sh openssh-server
openssh-server need an upgrade
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.
In particular, you should explain why an error exit from `apt-get` implies that upgrade is needed, and why you use such a cumbersome expression instead of simply `if apt-get ...;`

Comment: Doesn't work correctly, will give false positives. Example "firefox-utils" when "firefox" is passed.

Comment: OK fixed, add space in regexp !